# Comparing a string to a regular expression in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am receiving a Code in sms like "yyyy/mm-digit" (digit increments with every message). so i want to ensure that the code sent by user is exactly in that format otherwise another action. So how ?

Here is my code to check but it always execute else block, why ? Note: I want it for e.g. "2014/8-digit" kinda pattern , how ? (it changes with respect to year and month)

Here is my little effort but it's throwing dateitme conversion failed error plus it might have other issues too, Help

```
Alter PROCEDURE TestTrigger



AS
BEGIN
     Begin Try
           Declare @msg as varchar(20)
           SELECT @msg = '2014/9-1'

           DECLARE @yyyymm varchar(255) = Convert(Varchar ,(cast(year(@msg) as varchar(255)) + '/' +
                                right(cast(month(@msg) as varchar(255)), 2)
                               ));

                IF (@msg like @yyyymm + '-[0-9]%' and
                    @msg not like @yyyymm + '-%[^0-9]%'
                   )
                  BEGIN
                    Print 'Done'
                  END
                  ELSE
                  BEGIN
                    Print 'Not Done'
                  END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
     Select ERROR_MESSAGE() as ErrorMsg
    END CATCH

END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the `YEAR` and `MONTH` functions both expect a datetime parameter and `'2014/9-1'` is not a valid datetime.

Since you only really have two possible formats `yyyy/mm-digit` for months 10-12 and `yyyy/m-digit` for months 1-9 (assuming the year will be in the last 1000 years), you could use this comparison:

```
@msg LIKE '[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[1-9]-%'
OR @msg LIKE '[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[1][0-2]-%'
```

If you then need to check that the digit is a valid number, you can extract the digit using SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX, then check if any non numeric character appears:

```
NOT SUBSTRING(@msg, CHARINDEX('-', @msg) + 1, LEN(@msg)) LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

e.g.

```
SELECT  msg,
        ValidDate = CASE WHEN msg LIKE '[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[1-9]-%'
                                OR msg LIKE '[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[1][0-2]-%' 
                        THEN 1 
                        ELSE 0 
                    END,
        ValidDigit = CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(msg, CHARINDEX('-', msg) + 1, LEN(msg)) LIKE '%[^0-9]%' 
                            THEN 0 
                            ELSE 1 
                        END
FROM (VALUES ('2014/9-1'), ('201/9-2'), ('2014/13-3'), ('2014/9-A'), ('2014/0-15x')) t (msg);
```

So I think your code would be something like:

```
DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(20) = '2014/9-1';

IF ((@msg LIKE '[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[1-9]-%'
    OR @msg LIKE '[1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]/[1][0-2]-%')
    AND NOT SUBSTRING(@msg, CHARINDEX('-', @msg) + 1, LEN(@msg)) LIKE '%[^0-9]%')
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Done';
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Not Done';
    END
```